# Check if array is not empty - XHR response test

Tags: javascript, json, testing, httpresponse, testcafe

How can check-in TestCafe if an array is not empty? Thank you very much in advance for the help
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
const logRecord = logger.requests[0];
        const { statusCode, body } = logRecord.response;
        const array = body.toString();
        console.log(statusCode);
        console.log(JSON.parse(array));
        await t
            //check if status code is correct    
            .expect(logger.contains(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).ok('Status code is NOT correct')
            //check if array is not empty
            .expect(array.length).gt(0, 'Array is empty!');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a HTTP logger to check responses the tested page receives. Please check the [example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/#logging-http-requests) in the TestCafe documentation. Also, you might want to take a look at the following topic: [Logging HTTP Requests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html)

Comment: Hi aleks-pro. Thank you for answer. I already started implementig HTTP logger, but the problem is (this issue is not reproduceable anymore) that the status code was always 200 OK even if the array was empty. I need to test the content within the array response.